# RequireJS timeout when loading shim and named modules from same file

Tags: requirejs

I was playing around with mixing shims and paths configuration in RequireJS (v2.1.5) and ran into an issue. It looks like a bug, but maybe just be my lack of understanding. Here's a simple code sample:

I have this combined Javascript file, containing two amd modules and one global object, named *all.js*:

```
define("one", [], function() {
  return {
    log: function() {
      console.log("ONE");       }
    };
});
define("two", [], function() {
  return {
    log: function() {
        console.log("TWO");
    }
  };
});
window.three = {
  log: function() {
    console.log("THREE");
  } 
};
```

and here's the config:

```
<script>
    requirejs.config({          
        baseUrl: ".",
        paths: {
            one : "all",
            two: "all",
            three: "all"
        },
        shim: {
            three: {
                exports: "three"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, if I do this, I see ONE and TWO (ok):

```
require(["one", "two"], function(one, two) {
    one.log();
    two.log();
});
```

If I do this, the shim is loaded and I see THREE (ok):

```
require(["three"], function(three) {
    three.log();
});
```

But, if I combine the above, nothing happens and I get the error *Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: three*:

```
require(["one", "two", "three"], function(one, two, three) {
    one.log();
    two.log();
    three.log();
});
```

I do still see *all.js* loaded in my network panel though.

What's going wrong?